# Java - SubSet Sum Recursion Drawing of recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I have a problem understanding recursion of code, I tried to draw me tree follow, but something is not clear to me halfway.
Can someone please help me understand the code snippet, and draw on the page, or paint or any other software, the tree of recursion so that I can fully understand the code.

Why are there two recursion?
I do not understand how the second recursion works (After the ||).

[image: Example painted tree]

```
public static boolean hasSum(int[] array, int start, int sum) {
    if (sum == 0)
        return true;

    if (start > array.length - 1)
        return false;

    return hasSum(array, start + 1, sum - array[start])
            || hasSum(array, start + 1, sum);

}
```

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

The searched subset sum (i.e. `sum`) can either include the current element (`array[start]`) **or** (hence the `||`) not include the current element.

If it includes `array[start]`, we should find a subset of the sub-array starting in index `start+1` whose sum is `sum - array[start]`.

This is handled by `hasSum(array, start + 1, sum - array[start])`.

If it doesn't include `array[start]`, we should find a subset of the sub-array starting in index `start+1` whose sum is `sum` (i.e., since the current element doesn't participate in the sum, we have to find the same sum in a smaller array).

This is handled by `hasSum(array, start + 1, sum)`.

Hence the two recursive calls.

Comment: @liran What do you mean by "paint me"?

Comment: In a statement, I have attached a picture, the picture painted all recursive calls.
I would be happy if you could draw me to the page, as I paint only the steps in the correct order.
I'm relatively begins with java
And I still need to understand the code

Thank you

Comment: @liran Perhaps I'll try to explain some more - your code contains two recursive calls connected with an OR (||) condition. This means the first (left) call is executed first. If it returns true, there is no need to execute the other recursive call - the method returns true. If it returns false, the second (right) recursive call is executed and the result of that call is returned by the method.

Comment: @liran Your input array may contain negative elements, so even if the sum becomes negative at some point, the desired sum can still be reached (i.e. sum can still reach 0).